# template parameter deduction from templated non-type template argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-argument-deduction

I have the following typedef:

```cpp
template<typename G, typename T, typename R>
using my_func_type = typename R(T::*)(G, int) const;
```

It is a member function I use a lot, so I'm playing around with making different wrappers for. The premise is that I want an object that implements these functions through a common function call, so that I can combine them in different ways (currently I use the straightforward way of wrapping the call as a lambdas).

However, another method is to pass that function as a non-type template parameter (this improves my performance compared to the lambda solution, because I'm constantly evaluating it), viz.

```cpp
template<typename G, typename T, typename R, my_func_type<G, T, R> f>
struct MyWrapper
{
    MyWrapper(G g, T t) : g{ g }, t{ t } {}
    auto eval(int n) const
    {
        return (t.*f)(g, n);
    }

protected:
    G g;
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    AnObject g;
    TheCallingObject t;
    auto f = &TheCallingObject::callit;

    MyWrapper<AnObject, TheCallingObject, double, f> wrap(g, t)
}
```

But this seems a little redundant, so is it possible for the template arguments to be deduced from `f`?

The halfway solution I've found is:

```cpp
template<auto f, typename G, typename T>
struct MyWrapper
{
    OpFuncDerivative(G g, T t) : g{ g }, t{ t } {}
    auto eval(int n) const
    {
        return (t.*f)(g, n);
    }

protected:
    G g;
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    AnObject g;
    TheCallingObject t;
    auto f = &TheCallingObject::callit;

    // it won't automatically deduce AnObject and TheCallingObject 
    // through the parameters to the constructor though!
    MyWrapper<f, AnObject, TheCallingObject> wrap(g, t) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper function:

```
template<typename G, typename T, auto f>
struct MyWrapper
{
    MyWrapper(G g, T t) : g{g}, t{t}
    {}

    auto eval(int n) const
    {
       return (t.*f)(g, n);
    }

protected:
    G g;
    T t;
};

template<auto f, typename G, typename T>
MyWrapper<G, T, f> make_wrapper(G g, T t)
{
    return {g, t};
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    AnObject g;
    TheCallingObject t;
    constexpr auto f = &TheCallingObject::callit;

    auto wrap = make_wrapper<f>(g, t);
}
```